# How can I select a random listbox item with WWW::Mechanize?

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

With Perl's [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/) module, I want to select a random value from a select box. How can I do this? With `dump_forms` I can dump select box values, but how can I get them in an array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW::Mechanize) uses [HTML::Form](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::Form) for processing forms.  You can get the HTML::Form object with the `form_name` or `form_number` methods.  So, use something like this:

```
my $form = $mech->form_number(1);
my $select = $form->find_input('name_of_select_box');
my @values = $select->possible_values;
$select->value($values[int rand @values]); # Choose a possible value at random
```